# Не использовать blur() на родительский элемент, при фокусе на дочерний

Tags: javascript

Возникла такая проблема. У меня есть дочерний div и родительский. На родительский div установлен focus и blur. Но как сделать что бы при фокусе на дочернем элементе, не срабатывал blur на родительском? Кто понял о чем я, помогите пожалуйста.

Когда я нажимаю на child, на parent элемент срабатывает blur. Как это исправить?

```js
let p = document.querySelector(".parent")
let ch = document.getElementById("child");
p.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  p.classList.add("parent-after");
});
p.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  p.classList.remove("parent-after")
})
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.parent-after {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="parent">
  <div contenteditable="true" id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117206/discussion-on-question-by-matvey-boltach---blur--).

Answer (score 1):

```css
form {
  filter: blur(1px);
}

form:focus-within {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Возникла такая проблема. У меня есть дочерний div и родительский. На родительский div установлен focus и blur. Но как сделать что бы при фокусе на дочернем элементе, не срабатывал blur на родительском? Кто понял о чем я, помогите пожалуйста.
  <input>
</form>
```

Comment: я думал, что автор вопроса имеет ввиду события focus и blur в js

Comment: @Pavel, ok, готово.

Answer (score 0):

Полезность сомнительная - поддержка хуже чем у `:focus-within`, но можно попытаться их скомбинировать чтобы покрыть Edge 17-18.

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}

div {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}

:focus ~ div {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: none;
  backdrop-filter: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Возникла такая проблема. У меня есть дочерний div и родительский. На родительский div установлен focus и blur. Но как сделать что бы при фокусе на дочернем элементе, не срабатывал blur на родительском? Кто понял о чем я, помогите пожалуйста.
  <input>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я имел в виду blur не в css, а как событие в js, срабатывающее, когда элемент теряет фокус. https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur

Answer (score 0):

Только если `{ once: true }` может не поддерживаться, то придётся расписать руками на функцию, вызывающую, а затем снимающую обработчик.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
  console.log('focus')
})

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('blur', function handler(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.closest('form') === this) {
    e.relatedTarget.addEventListener('blur', handler.bind(this), { once: true })
    return console.log("Ignore blur")
  }
  
  console.log('blur')
})
```

```html
<p><input>
<form tabindex=0><input> <input></form>
<p><input>
```

Comment: Я имел виду немного другое. https://codepen.io/motyabolt/pen/QWKGeZY вот тут я создал проблемную ситуацию. Когда я нажимаю на child, на parent элемент срабатывает blur. Как это исправить?

Comment: @MatveyBoltach, пример почти такой же как и твой код, замени `form` на твой `parent`, а `input` внутри на `child` - и получится твой пример. Надо только обработчик поправить

Comment: @Grundy, кстати, если в обработчиках только добавление классов, то они вполне заменяются на решение с `:focus-within` :)